# A matching M in a graph G is a maximum matching if and only if G has no M -augmented path.

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Hi there is a theorem like this and there is a proof of that theorem. But i did not understand the proof even if i google it. Can anyone can help me with an understandable explanation?

Theorem:

> A matching M in a graph G is a maximum matching if and only if G has no M-augmented path.

Proof:

> The only-if part holds because we have a maximum matching (switching edges along the augmented path will increase the matching’s size which is a contradiction).
>
> Assume that M is a matching that has no M-augmented path. Assume also M' is a matching with larger size. The symmetric difference between M and M' contains either paths or cycles. Since there are no M-augmented paths the number of edges from M in each path in the symmetric difference is at least as much as the edges from M'. Cycles are even and they contain the same number of edges from each matching.Hence the size of M and M' is the same. Thus M and M' have the same number of edges a contradiction with M' having size greater than M.

Comment: Do you understand / can you describe what an M-augmented path is? That would probably help to understand your difficulties.

Comment: Draw a graph and choose two different matching, you will see it.

Comment: i draw the graph and understand the theorem but i did not understand the proof.

Comment: State which line you do not understand.

Answer (score -1):

This is result from original paper by [Hopcroft](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/%7Epettie/matching/Hopcroft-Karp-bipartite-matching.pdf). You should take a look at it

Comment: Please include the relevant contents of the paper in your answer. It is fine to link for reference and further reading if a viewer is interested, but everything needed to understand or accept an answer should be contained within this post.